# Phone log shows numbers not Contact Names after installing Samsung S3 Security Update

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-s-3, call-history

My Galaxy S3 was working great **until** I installed a security update yesterday (26/11/12).  Immediately after, the names dropped off the calls list and it is now showing phone numbers only.

Answer (score 0):

Contacted the customer support and they told to hard reboot the mobile. It worked for me. Please backup all your apps, contacts etc using Kies before doing a hard reboot as it will restore the mobile to it's factory settings. It is a pain but had to do it to get my phone back working.

Comment: I believe you mean "hard reset" or "factory reset" right?
In an Android context, hard "reboot" generally means holding a specific set of buttons or pulling the battery to force the phone to reboot